# Make an achor tag non-clickable for while and make it clickable again

Tags: javascript

How can I make an anchor tag clickable after few seconds ? I made it non-clickable but now can't make it clickable again.

(Note: there will be no id used for the tag)

Heres my html and javascript:

```
function neww(id,time){
    var sec,min,hr;
    var i=(time*1);
    var neew=setInterval(function(){
        if(i>0){
            i--;
            if(i>=60){
                min=parseInt(i/60);
                sec=i%60;         
                if(min>=60){
                    hr=parseInt(min/60);
                    min=min%60;
                }else{
                    hr=0;
                }
            }else{
                min=0;
                hr=0;
                sec=i;
            }
            if(sec<10){
                sec="0"+sec;
            }
            if(min<10){
                min="0"+min;
            }
            if(hr<10){
                hr="0"+hr;
            }
            id.onclick=function(){return false}; // its working here
            id.style.color="red";
            id.style.backgroundColor="#ffffff";
            id.innerHTML=hr+':'+min+':'+sec;
        }
        if(i==0){
            id.innerHTML="Ready";
            id.style.color="#ffffff";
            id.style.backgroundColor="green";
            if(id.onclick==false){id.onclick=function(){return true};} // but its not working
            clearInterval(neew);
        }
    },1000);
}
```

Html:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank" class="mynewclass" onclick="neww(this,5);">Ready</a>
```

-Thanks in advance.

***SOLVED:***

I just removed the 'onclick' attribute from the anchor, so the timer function gets no barrier until the timer completes. Thank you everybody for your effort which helped me to solve this.

Thiss for the link is alive but that doesn't interfere the timer function:

```
function neww(id,time){
    var link=id.getAttribute("onclick");
    id.removeAttribute("onclick");
    var sec,min,hr;
    var i=(time*1);
    var neew=setInterval(function(){
        if(i>0){
            i--;
            if(i>=60){
                min=parseInt(i/60);
                sec=i%60;         
                if(min>=60){
                    hr=parseInt(min/60);
                    min=min%60;
                }else{
                    hr=0;
                }
            }else{
                min=0;
                hr=0;
                sec=i;
            }
            if(sec<10){
                sec="0"+sec;
            }
            if(min<10){
                min="0"+min;
            }
            if(hr<10){
                hr="0"+hr;
            }
            id.style.color="red";
            id.style.backgroundColor="#ffffff";
            id.innerHTML=hr+':'+min+':'+sec;
        }
        if(i==0){
            id.innerHTML="Ready";
            id.style.color="#ffffff";
            id.style.backgroundColor="green";
            id.setAttribute("onclick",link);
            clearInterval(neew);
        }
    },1000);
}
```

And thiss for the link is dead while the timer is running:

```
function neww(id,time){
    var link=id.getAttribute("onclick");
    var linkk=id.getAttribute("href");    
    var sec,min,hr;
    var i=(time*1);//+60;
    var neew=setInterval(function(){
        if(i>0){
            i--;
            if(i>=60){
                min=parseInt(i/60);
                sec=i%60;         
                if(min>=60){
                    hr=parseInt(min/60);
                    min=min%60;
                }else{
                    hr=0;
                }
            }else{
                min=0;
                hr=0;
                sec=i;
            }
            if(sec<10){
                sec="0"+sec;
            }
            if(min<10){
                min="0"+min;
            }
            if(hr<10){
                hr="0"+hr;
            }
            id.removeAttribute("onclick");
            id.removeAttribute("href");
            id.style.color="red";
            id.style.backgroundColor="#ffffff";
            id.innerHTML=hr+':'+min+':'+sec;
        }
        if(i==0){
            id.innerHTML="Ready";
            id.style.color="#ffffff";
            id.style.backgroundColor="green";
            id.setAttribute("onclick",link);
            id.setAttribute("href",linkk);
            clearInterval(neew);
        }
    },1000);
}
```

Comment: Just a quick suggestion(untested): try changing `if(id.onclick==false)` to `if(id.onclick()==false)`

Comment: Have you tried using id.bind("click", function(){return true;});

Comment: @LcLK ,now the link is working but the timer function not working.

Comment: id.bind did not work

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/0wfgL0ow/ Also consider using setTimeout instead of setInterval for something that you are not using continously.

Comment: @nothing9, sorry, there are many anchor tags there and will be with no id. So theres no way to set a function only for 1 link. If I remove link then the anchor tag is still clickable which calls the timer function and then previously stored link in a variable becomes 'null', so I can't add that link in anchor tag again. I need to make the link unclickable and then clickable again after the timer resets.

Comment: Please make a fiddle out of it. I tried but for me the link is ALWAYS clickable.

Comment: Maybe it helps if we knew what the behaviour in the end should look like. So you have a link and when the user clicks it it should be unclickable for a couple of seconds, then afterwads it is clickable again?

Comment: Actually when a user clicks on a link, the timer will start to count down until the link will become valuable. you can say this 'the link becomes dead or valueless while the timer is running'.

Answer (score 1):

Here I am giving you one idea. please modify, according to your need. Hope it help.

*After three minutes, it will create the link.*

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank" class="mynewclass">Ready</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
  var link = $('.mynewclass').attr('href');
  $('.mynewclass').removeAttr('href');

  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.mynewclass').attr('href', link);
  }, 3000);
});
```

**Javascript:**
    I am using the javascript **getElementsByClassName** method. if you are using older browser then i think it will not work. please check the browser support.

```
window.onload = function () {
        var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('mynewclass'),
            urlLink = elem[0].getAttribute('href'),
            emptyURL = elem[0].removeAttribute('href');

    setTimeout(function () {
        urlLink = elem[0].setAttribute('href', urlLink);
    }, 3000);
}
```

Here is the jsbin link - http://jsbin.com/dawit/2/

Comment: ok. if you want in native javascript, then also you can achieve same functionality. ok. give me some time - i will give you the javascript code.

Comment: Wait, I did not want to critisize. :) Just wanted to avoid confusion. I recommend using jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

In Vanilla JavaScript:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Delay Click</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank" class="mynewclass">Ready</a> |
    <a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank" class="mynewclass">Ready</a> |
    <a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank" class="mynewclass">Ready</a> |

<script>
    var enableLinks = false;

    setTimeout(function(){
        enableLinks = true;
    }, 5000); //add delay of 5 seconds = 5000 miliseconds

    function clickHandler(e){
        var el = e.target;
        if(!enableLinks){
            e.preventDefault();
        }else{
            //add rest of your logic here
            console.log("it's working");
        }   
    }

    var anchors = document.querySelectorAll(".mynewclass");
    for(var i=0; i< anchors.length; i++){
    if (anchors[i].addEventListener) {
      anchors[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false); 
    } else if (anchors[i].attachEvent)  {
      anchors[i].attachEvent('onclick', clickHandler);
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry I can't use setTimeOut() because the timer function is showing the count down in every second. and please read the comment on the top which I made to 'nothing9'.